# Webrequest on mono does not recover after lost internet connection

Tags: c#, mono, webrequest

I have an embedded device that regular POST status to a backend. If the internet connection is lost I first get an timeout connection. Following call gives a “no router ConnectFailure (No route to host)” exception as expected.

However, when the internet connection is re-established, the call fails with timeout exception, and it does that forever. It seems like some resources are not released properly.
The code is working fine on native .net. 
Mono version is  5.12.0.226.
Does anyone have an idea what are the problem and if there is a solution?
The code looks like this:

```
private bool PostMessage(string message)
    {           
        try
        {                

            WebRequest webClient = WebRequest.Create(m_topicPostUrl);
            webClient.Method = "POST";
            webClient.Headers["Authorization"] = m_topicSAS;

            webClient.ContentType = "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);               
            webClient.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            using (Stream dataStream = webClient.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();

                using (WebResponse response = webClient.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd(); // data not used
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {

            AddMessageToLog(ex.Message);

        }

        return false;
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: From cmd.exe use >Netstat -a  which will give the status of the connection.  Do it on both client and server.  Most likely the connection never closed so you cannot open another connection with same source IP, destination IP, and port number until the first connection is closed.

Comment: hi jdweng, Thank you.

Comment: hi jdweng, Thank you. I tried that, and you are rigth. The connection stay "Established" on client even after 10 minutes without internet. (I don't have access to backend to do the check there). So I guess the mono implementation does not close as it should. Do you have an idea how to close the connection, preferable from mono.

Comment: Put the Connection in a using statement to when the code exits the using the connection will be disposed.

Comment: The webrequest is not disposeable? - and I already put the streams in using. But since this is working on native .net there must be some difference...can i force the connection to close when i enter this problem?

Comment: What about the client?